# What happens internally as and when the second statement in this code is executed?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

In the following C++ code, I am creating a class and declaring a private variable in that class.

```
#include <iostream>

class num{
    int k;
public:
    operator int(){
        return k;
    }
};

int main(){
    num obj;
    std::cout<<obj; // calls int()

    return 0;
}
```

On execution, this code will print the value of 'k' in 'obj' of type num. That clearly indicates that the member function of the class num has been invoked somehow. The invoked member function has the header 'operator int()', so, how does this function get invoked since I have not operated on obj and just printed it's value ?

Comment: the comment looks like a random bunch of words

Comment: @RoiHatam What? are? you? saying?

Comment: Implicit conversion of `num` to `int`. You could break it all using `explicit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code

```
operator int(){
    return k;
}
```

is a conversion of a `num` object to an `int` object. The conversion is **implicit** which means that it can be done automatically, i.e. even when you don't ask for it. In other words - if the compiler needs an `int` object but has a `num` object, the compiler will automatically call `int()` to convert `num` to an `int`.

Therefore you can do strange things like:

```
int n = 10 + obj;
```

and

```
void foo(int x)
{
    ....
}

foo(obj);
```

This goes even further... If the compiler needs a `<<` but `num` doesn't provide one, the compiler sees that it can convert `num` to `int` and that `int` has a `<<`. Consequently the compiler decides to do that.

A personal opnion:

It might seem smart to be able to convert some type to another type automatically. However, it is also confusing - especially to your co-workers. Therefore I'll recommend to avoid **implicit** conversions. If you need a conversion make it **explicity**. Then there will be no nasty surprises.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler looks for a valid overload of

```
operator<<(std::ostream&, something);
```

Since

```
operator<<(std::ostream&, num const&);
```

is not defined/provided, it looks for any allowed alternatives. Since `num` allows implicit type conversion to `int`, this is used, creating code equivalent to

```
std::cout<<static_cast<int>(num);
```

In fact, this is the exact reason for providing such an type-conversion operator: the type (`num` in this case) can be used instead of the conversion type in (almost) any function call w/o the need for explicit type conversion.